# Dividing the list in 8 instead of 5 in the median of median algorithms

Tags: algorithm, median-of-medians

[Image that explains the first algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY2xg.jpg)

[Generalized median-of-medians for sublist of size a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSQyB.jpg)

From this algorithm, we can see than in order to get linear running time for the algorithm, the constant has to be bigger than 4.
However, I wondered what would happen if I divided into n/8 sublists and chose the 4th biggest number of each sublist as the median.

I expected the running time to be linear, since 8 > 4 however when I calculated the running time, I found O(nlogn).
[Calculating for sublist of size 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuLBw.jpg)

Can someone please tell me if what I did is wrong, and explain to me why the sublist's size should always be odd?

Comment: As for your last point, the [Wiki page on Median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) states that `Firstly, computing median of an odd list is faster and simpler; while one could use an even list, this requires taking the average of the two middle elements, which is slower than simply selecting the single exact middle element.`

Comment: You got the recurrence relation wrong.  The algorithm doesn't recurse on both halves.  T(5n/16) part should be T(n/8), representing the recursive quickselect on the medians.